# Should the distribution of composite scores be normally distributed?

Tags: normal-distribution, scales, composite

**Should the distribution of composite scores be normal (bell curve)?**

The composite scores that I have developed is from a weighting of their separate components.

The component scores are in response to a normal survey (i.e. proper sampling proceedures were used). I have then weighted the scores (according to a basic formula that factors in their level of importance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking that if you're given an arbitrary random vector ${\bf X} = \{ X_{1}, ..., X_{p} \}$ with associated weights ${\bf w} = \{w_{1}, ..., w_{p} \}$, then is the distribution of

$$ {\rm composite \ score} = \sum_{k=1}^{p} w_{k} X_{k} $$

normal. The answer is not necessarily. If $p=2$ and $X_{1}, X_{2}$ are independent ${\rm Bernoulli}(1/2)$ then one composite score would be $X_{1}+X_{2}$, which certainly is not normal.

If each component of the composite score is normal, then the composite score will certainly be normal, but I don't know of any less general sufficient conditions.